# How to map File.setReadable to NIO Path operations

Tags: java, nio

What is the 'new' way to accomplish `File.setReadable` independent of platform? Is it PosixFilePermissions or something else?

Comment: [Files.setPosixFilePermissions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setPosixFilePermissions-java.nio.file.Path-java.util.Set-)

Comment: OK, that's what I hoped. Care to make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [setPosixFilePermissions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setPosixFilePermissions-java.nio.file.Path-java.util.Set-) method of `Files` class like:

```
Set<PosixFilePermission> permissions = new HashSet<PosixFilePermission>();
permissions.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
permissions.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);
permissions.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE);
permissions.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);
permissions.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_WRITE);
permissions.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_EXECUTE);
permissions.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ);
permissions.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_WRITE);
permissions.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_EXECUTE);
Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Paths.get("file.ext"), permissions);
```